# loop hierarchical custom post type, child pages only

Tags: wp-query

I need to query all pages of a custom post type that are children, not just children of a specific page. different way to say it is exclude all parent pages from a query of a custom post type.

never would've thought this was such a PITA

Comment: Have you tried `'post_parent__not_in' => array( 0 )`? https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/#post-page-parameters

Comment: that's the ticket! Thanks a million Jacob!

Comment: @JacobPeattie you should post that answer as an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php
// query only child pages of custom post type
$customQuery = array(
    'post_type' => 'CUSTOM_POST_TYPE',
    'posts_per_page' => '10',
    'post_parent__not_in' => array(0),
    );
$custom = new WP_Query( $customQuery );
if ($custom->have_posts()) :
while ( $custom->have_posts()) : $custom->the_post();
?>

DO STUFF
            
<?php endwhile;
endif;
wp_reset_query(); ?>
```